# NVL - функция SQL Developer, как корректно перевести на Postgres

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, sqldeveloper

Перевожу запрос SQL Developer:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT
          sCall.id AS call_object_id,
                       '<a href="https://help.company.ru/sd/operator/#uuid:serviceCall$'
                    || sCall.id
                    || '">'
                    || sCall.title
                    || '</a>'
                       AS Call_link,
          sCall.title AS call_id,
          NVL (mark.code, 0) AS mark
FROM nausd40.tbl_serviceCall sCall,
          nausd40.tbl_mark mark
where    
sCall.mark = mark.id(+)
```

Мой перевод на Postgres:

```
select DISTINCT
          sCall.id AS call_object_id,
              '<a href="https://help.company.ru/sd/operator/#uuid:serviceCall$'
                    || sCall.id
                    || '">'
                    || sCall.title
                    || '</a>'
                       AS Call_link,
          sCall.title AS call_id,
          COALESCE(mark.code, 0) AS mark
FROM tbl_serviceCall sCall
left join tbl_mark mark on (sCall.mark = mark.id)
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
SQL Error [42804]: ERROR: COALESCE types character varying and integer cannot be matched
```

Подскажите, что сделал не так.

Comment: `COALESCE(mark.code :: integer, 0) AS mark`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема с типом колонки `code`. Он судя по всему текстовый. coalesce в этом случае получает 1 параметр строку, а второй - целочисленный. Нужно чтоб типы совпадали.

Как именно исправить зависит от смысла этого поля, похоже, что оно должно быть типа integer. Либо сделать явное привидение типа в самом запросе.